# How to get network usage of a remote machine

Tags: java, network-programming, network-monitoring

I want to get some statistics from remote machines in my cluster. Using `SSH` and `JCraft` library, I connect to each machine's OS (Ubuntu) and run some command to get data about Disk usage and network usage. The bottleneck is the command that gets network data, `dstat -n 1 1`. It adds about 7 seconds to the process of gathering data from remote machines. I guess the problem is because it will listen to the ports for a second and this will cause the delay. Is any faster way to get network usage from a remote machine using Java?

Comment: What is your definition of "network usage"? It can easily be done for individual interfaces, given that you only need network packets sent/received by that adapter!

Comment: @Am_I_Helpful I mean the overall send and receive bytes of a machine.